# jquery autocomplete is not working with php mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Testing a autocomplete textbox jquery with PHP MySQL to get client name, data is not retrieving from the database.

I am giving here the PHP script table structure and HTML. I am not able to find the issue...

I had already read some questions regarding this but nothing solve my problem actually I am new to jquery

Thanks

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Document</title>
        <!-- jquery -->
        <script src="assests/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- jquery ui -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#clientName').autocomplete({
                source: 'php_action/fetchClient.php',
                minLength: 2,
                response: function(event, ui) {
                    // ui.content is the array that's about to be sent to the response callback.
                    if (ui.content.length === 0) {
                        $("#empty-message").text("No results found");
                        }
                    else {
                        $("#empty-message").empty();
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="clientName" class="form-control" autocomplete="on">
    </body>

</html>
```

**PHP SCRIPT**

```
<?php
    //get search term
    $searchTerm = trim ($_GET['term']);
    //get matched data from skills table
    $query = $con ->query("SELECT * FROM client WHERE client_Name LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY client_Name ASC");]\
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row['client_Name'];
    }
    //return json data
    echo json_encode($data); 
?>
```

**Database table**

```
INSERT INTO `client` (`clientID`, `client_Name`, `client_Company_Name`, `client_status`, `client_Company_Address`, `client_GST_Number`, `client_Mobile`, `client_Landline`) VALUES
(1, 'test', '', b'1', 'rohini delhi', 0, 0, 0),
(2, 'bbb', '', b'0', '', 33333, 2222, 33312),
(3, 'AAA', '', b'0', '', 33333, 2222, 33312),
(4, 'ccc', '', b'0', '', 33333, 2222, 33312);
```

**Dom consol error**

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   [this is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wlrf.png)

Comment: 404 is nothing about PHP, check your URLS.

Comment: `$('#search-input')` - You don't have any matching element in your HTML.  As for your 404 error, which resource is failing to load?  Your PHP code is also wide open to SQL injection, which is highly error-prone.  There also appear to be syntax errors in your PHP.  And you're trying to use variables you never defined.  It seems like there's ***a lot*** wrong here.  It's not clear how you even expect any of this to work.

Comment: Troubleshooting tip for web services like autocomplete. First, access the web service just from a browser. `https://example.com/php_action/fetchClient.php?term=something` might work for you.  When you're satisfied your web service does something reasonable, then integrate it into your web page Javascript. Use the Javascript F12 debugger to set breakpoints (in the source panel) and look at network requests (in the network panel).

Comment: sorry for the typo i correct the element error. but even still code is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.404 issue is due to my error display is off using Ubuntu recently after that I fix the problem let me update and close the problem for good..
thanks for helping..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#clientName").autocomplete({
        source: 'php_action/fetchClient.php'

    });
});

<?php
    include('core.php');
    //get search term
    $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
    //get matched data from skills table
    $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM client WHERE client_Name LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY client_Name ASC");
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row['client_Name'];
    }    
    //return json data
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found few issues.

1) **404** issue only occurs when your `source` is wrong.

2) In your PHP script there is an extra `]\` after `mysql` Query line.

3) If you want only `client_Name` then **fetch** only `client_Name` instead of `*`